# Kotlin MutableList Contains Value

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to determine if a mutable list contains string but I am getting a receiver type mismatch?

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Composable
    fun CheckboxSample(
        checkOptions: List<String>,
        selectedOptions: MutableState<List<String>>,
```

```
@Composable
    fun ElevatedButtonSample(
selectedOptions: MutableState<List<String>>)
```

```
var checkComp by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf(false)
```

```
checkComp = selectedOptions.contains("Compliance Fee") // **contains** is giving me the error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
checkComp = selectedOptions.value.contains("Compliance Fee")
```

`selectedOptions` is a `MutableState<List<String>>` and `.value` return `List<String>` which you can use to process further.

---

Also, You can refer to the UDF principle for architecturing your components. You should not have `MutableState` as a `Composable` parameter.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf

Comment: Figured it out with your answer, thank you!